# socket logback log receiver required

Tags: java, network-programming, logback

I am using logback in my application with socketappender. I want to get input of the socket appender in my java class. I want to show the output on my JFrame window.

I'll be appreciated for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. I create a class for simple network receiver. The backlog sends on network LoggingEventVO object. I just grab it and get the message from it. It work for me.